# How to use gradle-enterprise-maven-extension behind a proxy?

Tags: maven, gradle, migration

Willing to use the gradle-enterprise-maven-extension 
to migrate a project from maven to gradle, 
I cloned the [maven-build-scan-quickstart](https://github.com/gradle/maven-build-scan-quickstart) provided by the gradle team.

But runing `mvn install`, as specified, after acceptation of gradle terms of service, 
I receive the following message: 
`UnknownHostException: scans-in.gradle.com`

I tried to configure the proxy in several manners:

1. Using commannd line option: 
   `mvn install -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost:8888 -Dhttps.proxyPort=localhost:8888`
2. Using a gradle.properties file in a directory at %GRADLE_USER_HOME% directory location:
   (proxy is also configured in maven's settings.xml and need no password it works fine when using maven in standard ways)

gradle.properties :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8888
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost|127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8888
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost|127.0.0.1
```

But I still receive the same message:

```
~/github/maven-build-scan-quickstart
$ mvn install
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  3.830 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-31T13:09:19+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 7 goals, 7 executed
    Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? (yes/no): yes
    [INFO] Gradle Terms of Service accepted.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Publishing build scan...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] A network error occurred.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] The hostname 'scans-in.gradle.com' could not be resolved.
    [INFO] You may be disconnected from the Internet.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] If you require assistance with this problem, please report it via https://gradle.com/help/plugin and include the following information via copy/paste.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ----------
    [INFO] Maven version: 3.6.2
    [INFO] Extension version: 1.3.3
    [INFO] Request URL: https://scans-in.gradle.com/in/maven/3.6.2/1.3.3
    [INFO] Request ID: 1234567e-abcd-23de-c2d3-3fbbccd14a32
    [INFO] Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: scans-in.gradle.com
    [INFO] ----------
    [INFO]
```

Comment: I would ask the enterprise support of Gradle ....

Comment: Thanks do it and tell me ;-)

Comment: @khmarbaise ... Since this is the official quickstart of a tool provided for free I expect not to require entreprise support from Gradle ...

Comment: Maybe I don't get things wrong but this https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/maven-extension/ is needed ?

Comment: ok thanks, more explanations here, the extention needs a configuration file as explained here https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/maven-extension/#configuration_reference . Will work on it later. Thanks